# Understanding CPU Power

Tags: linux, windows-10, cpu, cloud, cpu-cores

[image: Plz see http://imgur.com/a/C42pC]

Here, it says 2 cores and 4 logical processors. There is 1 socket.

When I see Virtual machines in the cloud they say something like 8 vCPUs.

I wanted to understand:

1. What is the relation between cores and logical processors?
2. Higher core means better CPU? Higher logical processor means better CPU?
3. Is 8 vCPU machine 4 times faster than my desktop with 2 cores?
4. What is the socket here?
5. Also separately, after seeing [this](https://superuser.com/questions/439134/terminology-used-for-cpu-processors?rq=1), I am now totally confused as to how many processors actually run on my system above. And will I gain anything by using a VM in the cloud with say 8 vCPUs?
6. What VM (no of vCPUs) should I use if I want higher processing power than my desktop above?

As per the comments, I now understand that the question can't be answered in vacuum. Please take the required assumptions.

I am really not getting all this, Please help me understand. And I know a lot of my friends, who have been programming for years don't understand either.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that Virtual CPUs in the context of virtual machines are entirely unlike CPUs with their physical and logical cores. With hypervisors, there may be no relationship between physical cores and virtual cores. Logical processors come from Intel Hyperthreading on i7s, and none of your questions can be answered in a vacuum; they all depend on the workload. the more cores, the more tasks you can do semi-simultaenously, but the higher the frequency, the faster each task completes. how this will perform depends on the workload.

Comment: "Is 8 vCPU machine 4 times faster than my desktop with 2 cores?" - No

Comment: "What VM (no of vCPUs) should I use if I want higher processing power than my desktop above?" - Whatever virtual machine software you want.  Your VM isn't going to be more powerful then a physical machine, unless you have a server that is more powerful then a physical machine, virtualizing that more powerful computer.  Your question is extremely broad.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, thx for the comment. Like I say I provision a 32 vCPU VM on the cloud. Will it be 16 times faster? Of course, I am not talking about the software, they have a list of prices https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing based on the machine type. What machine should I use if say I want that to be 10 times faster than my desktop. Roughly. This was the question 6 actually. Thanks.

Comment: core count is entirely determined by how many tasks (threads) you want to run at the exact same time. if you only have one thread, then it will use exactly one core. if you have two threads, but only one core, the two threads will share the core by pausing while the other runs. if you have two cores however, both these tasks can be run at the same time, one on each core. So you question depends entirely on the software in use, and how many threads it uses at your average workload. so no, more cores does not mean "faster", but it does mean it can do more, which may reduce time to completion.